# Instale mi sistema en un hosting- public html y no pasa del login

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

[image: login de la pagina web]

index.php aqui en el index llamo al controlador plantilla

```
<?php

require_once "controladores/Plantilla.Controlador.php";
require_once "controladores/usuario.controlador.php";
require_once "modelos/usuario.modelo.php";


$plantilla = new PlantillaControlador();
$plantilla -> CargarPlantilla();
```

en el archivo plantilla controlador es el que carga las plantillas y los archivos

```
<?php

class PlantillaControlador{

    public function CargarPlantilla(){
        include "vistas/plantilla.php";
    }

}

?>
```

aqui hay un if donde si encuenta una session de usuario entonces
carga los modulos, si no carga el login

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_GET["cerrar_sesion"]) && $_GET["cerrar_sesion"] == 1) {

    session_destroy();
    
    echo '
        <script>
            window.location = "localhost/funcamiref/"
        </script>

        ';
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<?php if (isset($_SESSION["usuario"])) : ?>

    <body class="hold-transition sidebar-mini">
        <div class="wrapper">

            <?php
            // include "modulos/navbar.php";
            include "modulos/aside.php";
            ?>

            <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
            <div class="content-wrapper">

                <?php include "vistas/" . $_SESSION['usuario']->vista ?>

            </div>
            <!-- /.content-wrapper -->

            <?php include "modulos/footer.php"; ?>

        </div>
        <!-- ./wrapper -->

        <script>
            function CargarContenido(pagina_php, contenedor, id_perfil, id_modulo) {
                $("." + contenedor).load(pagina_php);
            }
        </script>

    </body>

<?php else : ?>

    <body>
        <?php include "vistas/login.php" ?>
    </body>

<?php endif; ?>
</html>
```

en el login lo que hago es llamar a el controlador que hace la validacion del usuario y la contraseña para despues redireccionar o decir contraseña o usuario invalido

```
public function login()
    {
        if (isset($_POST["loginUsuario"])) {


            $usuario = $_POST["loginUsuario"];
            $password = crypt($_POST["loginPassword"], '$2a$07$azybxcags23425sdg23sdfhsd$');

            $respuesta = UsuarioModelo::mdlInisiarSesion($usuario, $password);

            if (count($respuesta) > 0) {
                $_SESSION['usuario'] = $respuesta[0];

                echo '
                    <script>
                        window.location = "http://localhost/funcamiref/"
                    </script>

                    ';
            } else{
                echo '
                    <script>

                        fncSweetAlert(
                            "error",
                            "Usuario y/o contraseña invalida",
                            "http://localhost/funcamiref/"
                        );
                    </script>

                    ';
            }
        }
    }
```

en el controlador es donde encuentra si hay un usuario y contrasela en la base de datos entonces redirecciona a la siguiente duireccion y si no muestra el mensaje de contraseña/usuario invalido

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], He visto que has agregado Imágenes, es preferible que tus ejemplos sean en texto y facilites el uso del mismo, También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: El código y los mensajes de error siempre _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden ver las imágenes. Lee [ask].

Comment: Podrias usar  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] para acceder a la ruta del directorio raiz dinamicamente. Por ejemplo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/funcamiref";

Comment: Verifica tus rutas, tendrás que usar rutas absolutas para que encuentre tus archivos php correctamente.